# user session not being stored after they have logged in

Tags: php, session, authentication, pdo

I am creating a login system using oop pdo. When I log the user in, the session is not being created. I think it has something to do with my database class. The user's credentials are correct in the database and the connection credentials are correct.

user class:

```
class USER
{

    public function login($uname,$upass)
    {
       try
       {
          $stmt = Database::getInstance()->getConnection()->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname  LIMIT 1");
          $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname));
          $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
          {
             if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
             {
             $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
                return true;
             }
             else
             {
                return false;
             }
          }
       }
       catch(PDOException $e)
       {
           echo $e->getMessage();
       }
   }
```

database class:

```
<?php
class Database {


    private $_connection;
    private static $_instance; //The single instance


    /*
    Get an instance of the Database
    @return Instance
    */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!self::$_instance) { // If no instance then make one
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
    // Constructor
    private function __construct() {


try
{
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=hostnmae;dbname=database name'; // define host name and database name
    $username = 'username'; // define the username
    $pwd='password'; // password
    $this->_connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $pwd);


}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
     echo $e->getMessage();
}

    }
    // Magic method clone is empty to prevent duplication of connection
    private function __clone() { }
    // Get mysqli connection
    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->_connection;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where is your `session_start()` ?

Comment: its in my init.php file which is included into my header.php which is at the top of every page

Comment: I am using obj_start() in my header file could this be the reason

Answer (score 0):

yes you need session_start() in your init.php
and ob_start needs to be called before session_start